# QuartzCore not drawing corner radius

Tags: objective-c, ios

I added the QuartzCore framework to my ios 5.0 project and then tried

```
[self layer] setCornerRadius:10.0f];
```

and nothing happens to the view; it still a rectangle. What should I check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting mask to bounds property.

```
self.layer.maskToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Actually clipToBounds is a UIView property, to get the same effect on CALayer you need to set `self.layer.maskToBounds = YES;`